# Selenium/Java, how to find a partial link inside a text?

Tags: java, android

I am writing a test for Android app with Selenium. On the screen, I have a TextView with some text which contains a link. For example:

> Please, **Sign In** with an existing username..."

"Sign In" is a link that I need to find a Selenium driver and simulate a click on it.

I am able to find the view with an ID, or with a complete text, but I am unable to simulate a tap only on the Sign In:

```
androidDriver.findElement(By.id("com.somePackageName:id/SignInView")).click();
```